# Bootstrap 5 Dropdown Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, html, django, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 along Django to develop a website and I'm having issues getting a dropdown to function correctly. I have copied this code from w3schools exactly how it is and it is not working when I load the HTML. I've tried running it on the latest version of Chrome and Firefox and still no success. Does it have to do with the Bootstrap CDN?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container mt-3">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .dropdown class is used to indicate a dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>Use the .dropdown-menu class to actually build the dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown".</p>                                          
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just do it

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't what your exact problem is but this worked for me when I had the same issue.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```